# Extending boost tree

Tags: c++, boost, tree

I would like to augment a Boost [RB Tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost/intrusive/rbtree_algorithms.html). I've managed to create my node struct and plug that into the RB Tree.

Now I would like to add additional functionality when a rotation occurs. Essentially, I want to manipulate certain values in the nodes being rotated. I figured I could insert this functionality into the [tree_algorithms::rotate_right](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/boost/intrusive/detail/tree_algorithms.hpp) and tree_algorithms::rotate_left functions.

I'm not familiar with extending Boost classes... And these functions aren't even members of a class (which I could extend and then override the method) - it's a static function. So how could I augment that function or replace it with my own flavor?

Comment: Anything under a "detail" namespace anywhere in Boost is NOT intended to be used directly, as they may change from release to release in ways which would break code if you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I am able to accomplish what I want using the node::set_left_node and node::set_right_node methods. This isn't ideal, since the action I want to perform **ONLY** needs to be performed on the two rotating nodes (when a rotation actually occurs). Instead, the action will be performed for all nodes involved in a movement of any kind.